# Getting all the points within boost polygon

Tags: c++, boost, boost-polygon

I want to get all the points(with integer valued indices) within the boundary of a polygon. There is an API function to query if the point is inside a polygon but I want to get the list of all the points. Is there any API functionality in boost library to do this?

Polygons are defined by vertices but there are several well know methods such as flood fill or scan line technique to get interior points of the polygon. However, I couldn't find any implementation of these methods in boost.

Comment: The number of points inside a polygon or on its boundary is infinite (for unlimited precision, but still huge for finite precision). Doesn't this bother you?

Comment: It's a geometry library, not a drawing primitives library.

Comment: In boost polygon library, vertices have integer indices. Therefore, I am only interested in points with integer valued indices. Sorry for confusion